# How to get the animation resource inside a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf

....

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="OnChecking">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="slider"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="SplineValue"
                                                  KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000"
                                                  Value="25" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="OnUnchecking">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="slider"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000"
                                                  Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                                          Storyboard.TargetName="slider"
                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000"
                                                     Value="1,1,1,1" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

....

I can get the Resource "OnChecking" in the code behind using the below statement.

```
Storyboard stb1 = this.Template.Resources["OnChecking"] as Storyboard;
```

But How can i get the "SplineValue" SplineDoubleKeyFrame inside the Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
 Storyboard stb1 = chk.Template.Resources["OnChecking"] as Storyboard;
 DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation =
                       (DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)stb1.Children[0];
 var val = ((SplineDoubleKeyFrame)animation.KeyFrames[0]).Value;
```